# How to use SharedPreferences in Android to store, fetch and edit values?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I want to store a score and name value and need to retrieve and edit it whenever a user gets higher score. How can I do that? Can somebody help me here using my code please?

**MainActivity.java**

```js
package com.thesis.boggleit;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 //VARIABLES HERE
  
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      
      
        dbHelper =new DBAdapter(this);
        search = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textHere);
      
  OnClickListener myCommoClickListner = new OnClickListener(){

   @Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
          Log.i(TAG,"arg0.getId()="+arg0.getId());
                
                
                if (arg0.getId()==R.drawable.a){
                    Log.i(TAG,"arg0.getId()="+arg0.getId());
                    generatedString=generatedString+("a");
                    text.setText(generatedString);
                    ((ImageButton) arg0).setImageResource(R.drawable.changea);

            if (!timeHasStarted) {
                countDownTimer.start();
                timeHasStarted = true;
                }
         }
   
  };
  image1.setOnClickListener(myCommoClickListner);
    }
    
    //TIMER HERE
    private int optionTxtView = 0  ;
    private int addClick = 0  ;
    
    private void calculate(){
  x = Integer.parseInt(tv3.getText().toString().replaceAll("\\s",""));
     y = Integer.parseInt(tv2.getText().toString().replaceAll("\\s",""));
     z = x + y;
     score.setText(Integer.toString(z));
     }

     String s1= search.getText().toString();
        String s2= dbHelper.getData(s1);
      
........

}
```

**TIA**

Comment: try using this  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values

Comment: Lab, any error are you getting in saving or fetching???

Comment: The activity won't load whenever I put the sharedpref cde.

Answer (score 0):

The [Official Android developer guide](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html) clearly states that

> If you have a relatively small collection of key-values that you'd like to save, you should use the SharedPreferences APIs. A SharedPreferences object points to a file containing key-value pairs and provides simple methods to read and write them. Each SharedPreferences file is managed by the framework and can be private or shared.

This means you have to use the `SharedPreferences` class to achieve what you want.

Example:-

`SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
// In a fragment`

`SharedPreferences sharedPref = getApplicationContext().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
//In an Activity`
 Best way to learn is to visit the above link and read it.

Answer (score 0):

Storing values

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putString("name", name);
editor.putInt("score", score);
editor.commit();
```

Getting values

```
String name = prefs.getString("name", "");
int score = prefs.getInt("score", 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this Common class:

```
public static boolean setPreference(Context context, String key, int value) {

    if (context == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("'context' must not be null.");
    }
    if (key == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("'key' must not be null.");
    }

    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putInt(key, value);
    return editor.commit();
} 
public static int getPreference(Context context, String key, int defValue) {

    if (context == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("'context' must not be null.");
    }
    if (key == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("'key' must not be null.");
    }

    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    return preferences.getInt(key, defValue);
}
```

How to use :

```
int currentScore = 20; 
    PreferenceUtil.setPreference(context, "key1", currentScore);

    //get. If the key1 in not available, return default value 0

    int myScore = PreferenceUtil.getPreference(context, "key1", 0);
```